# Как в Selenium получить код завершения запроса GET?

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь перебирать страницы на сайте, пока не дойду до последней:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
j=1
while True:
    url = f"http://..../page{j}.html"
    browse.get(url)
    # Как проверить результат запроса GET ?
    j = j+1
```

В прекрасном супе метод *get()* возвращает код завершения. А в селениуме ничего не возвращается и даже исключения не возбуждаются при ошибках.

Как быть ?

Comment: "В прекрасном супе" че за эверь и где обитает? Может все таки requests?

Comment: - " че за эверь и где обитает? "
- BeautifulSoup. Дока тут: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: а причем тогда медот get() из библиотеки BeautifulSoup? BeautifulSoup не умеет посылать запросы, веть browse.get(url) это посылка запроса на определенный адрес. И как я понял вы хотите получить статус код запроса?

Comment: - "а причем тогда метод get() из библиотеки BeautifulSoup?" - Не причём, почти. Просто суп практически всегда используется в связке с библиотекой  Requests. С моей точки зрения - это объединение. Т.е. сначала получает текст HTML с помощью Requests, а потом парсим его с помощью BeautifulSoup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519156/how-to-get-status-code-in-selenium-chrome-web-driver-in-python

Comment: Почитал, спасибо! Но, честно говоря, не очень радужно это выглядит :-(

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, простого и лаконичного способа нет. Есть пару "танцев с бубном", чтобы это реализовать. Они представлены в [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63876668), также там подробна расписана причина, почему разработчики так и не реализовали метод для получения *status code*.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)